# if two n bit numbers are multiplied then the result will be maximum how bit long

Tags: math, binary

I was wondering if there is any formula or way to find out much maximum bits will be required if two n bits binary number are multiplied.
I searched a lot for this but was unable to find its answer anywhere.

Comment: Probably better on Programmer's exchange or Math exchange.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiplication of two 16-bit numbers - Why is the result 32-bit long?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21416792/multiplication-of-two-16-bit-numbers-why-is-the-result-32-bit-long)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It can be simply concluded using examples:

> 11*11(since 11 is the maximum 2 bit number)=1001(4 bit)
>
> 111*111=110001(6 bit)
>
> 1111*1111=11100001(8 bit)
>
> 11111*11111=1111000001(10 bit)

and so from above we can see your answer is 2*n

Comment: Thank-you it was simple to get it

Comment: Simple conclusion using examples is not, generally speaking, a good idea.

Comment: But is helpful for better understanding

Comment: But it is not a proof.

Comment: if there are n and m bits involved, then simply add n and m: n+m bits.

Answer (score 14):

Number of digits in base B required for representing a number N is floor(log_B(N)+1). Logarithm has this nice property that log(X*Y)=log(X)+log(Y), which hints that the number of digits for X*Y is roughly the sum of the number of digits representing X and Y.

Answer (score 8):

The easiest way to think about this is to consider the maximum of the product, which is attained when we use the maximum of the two multiplicands.

If value `x` is an n-bit number, it is at most 2^n - 1.  Think about this, that 2^n requires a one followed by n zeroes.

Thus the largest possible product of two n-bit numbers will be:

(2^n - 1)^2 = 2^(2n) - 2^(n+1) + 1

Now n=1 is something of a special case, since 1*1 = 1 is again a one-bit number.  But in general we see that the maximum product is a 2n-bit number, whenever n > 1.  E.g. if n=3, the maximum multiplicand is `x=7` and the square 49 is a six-bit number.

Comment: Nice!! maybe 2n is due to taking log2. log2(2^(2n) - 2^(n+1) + 1) ~ log2(2^(2n)) = 2n.

Comment: @hardmath I realized that as I posted, however, by your formula (using the right-hand side), I still get the wrong answer. Suppose I multiply 7 * 7 in binary: 111 * 111 = 110001. Your formula says:
2^(2*3) - 2^(3+1) + 1 = 49. That is the maximum *value*, NOT the maximum length in bits (which is what the question asked for), and which is 6.

Comment: @hardmath One other minor thing: you said to think of it as 2^n "followed by n zeroes", but you should really think of it as "followed by n ones", since setting those bits obtains the true maximum value due to the carry-over.

Comment: @snd: 2^n truly has as its binary representation a "one followed by n zeros".  Thus 2^n requires n+1 bits.  However 2^n - 1 only requires n bits.  Are we in some disagreement about this?

Comment: @hardmath No disagreement, I misread you entirely. You are correct on all counts! Apologies for wasting time, coding all night and overtired.

Answer (score 4):

It's worth noting that the base of the positional system doesn't matter. Whatever formula you come up with for the decimal multiplication will work for the binary multiplication.

Let's apply a bit of deduction and multiply two numbers that have relatively prime numbers of digits: 2 and 3 digits, respectively.

1. Smallest possible numbers:

   10 * 100 = 1000 has 4 digits
2. Largest possible numbers:

   99 * 999 = 98901 has 5 digits

So, for a multiplication of n-digit by m-digit number, we deduce that the upper and lower limits are `n+m` and `n+m-1` digits, respectively. Let's make sure it holds for binary as well:

1. 10 * 100 =  1000 has 4 digits
2. 11 * 111 = 10101 has 5 digits

So, it does hold for binary, and we can expect it to hold for any base.

Comment: Are you aware of a proof for this?

Comment: Such awareness belongs on math stackexchange :)

Comment: What made you choose relatively prime bit-widths, 2 and 3, as opposed to  non-coprime bit-widths like 2 and 4?

Comment: Seemed like a safer choice :)

Answer (score 3):

x has n binary digits means that 2^(n-1) <= x < 2^n, also assume that y has m binary digits. That means:

```
2^(m+n-2)<=x*y<2^(m+n)
```

So x*y can have m+n-1 or m+n digits. It easy to construct examples where both cases are possible:

- m+n-1: 2*2 has 3 binary digits (m = n = 2)
- m+n: 7*7=49=(binary)110001 has 6 binary digits and m = n = 3

Comment: IIRC it gets a little hairy if you're dealing with 2s complement signed.  (But it's been 30 years since I mucked with this stuff.)

Comment: why does m+n-2 imply it can have m+n-1 digits?

Comment: Like I mentioned in the beginning - number of digits is defined by between what powers of two the number lies. You can see for example - 2^3 > 5 >= 2^2, so 5 has 3 digits in binary representation (101)