# Multiplication of two 16-bit numbers - Why is the result 32-bit long?

Tags: assembly, binary, multiplication, bit, integer-arithmetic

If I multiplie two 16-bit numbers, the result will be 32-bit long. But why is this so?
What is the clear explanation for this?

And for my right understanding:
The calculation for this is: n-bit number multiplied with a m-bit number gives a (n+m) bit number?

Comment: It is up to the processor designer how they want to handle multiplication. Some choose to return a truncated single-precision result. Others return a full double-precision result.

Comment: This is not the answer which i searched for. This rule is not only for assembly or computers. A Math-Example: The multiplie of two numbers (each number has 2 digits) gives a result-number with 4 digits. But why? I search a clean, logical explanation for this.

Comment: This is a math question, not a programming question. "Why does multiplying two two-digit numbers result in a four-digit number?" Try http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: "And for my right understanding: The calculation for this is: n-bit number multiplied with a m-bit number gives a (n+m) bit number?" So what do you get when m=16 and n=16?

Answer (score 6):

> (2<sup>n</sup> - 1)*(2<sup>m</sup> - 1) = 2<sup>n+m</sup> - 2<sup>n</sup> - 2<sup>m</sup> + 1

**-(2<sup>n</sup> + 2<sup>m</sup>)** is like clearing the bits at index *n* and *m*, which does not affect much the result compared to 2<sup>n+m</sup>, so you need n+m bits to represent the result.

For example **1111<sub>2</sub>*1111<sub>2</sub> = 11100001<sub>2</sub>** (15*15 = 225)

In general, **(b<sup>n</sup> - 1)*(b<sup>m</sup> - 1) = b<sup>n+m</sup> - b<sup>n</sup> - b<sup>m</sup> + 1**, so multiply an n-digit by an m-digit number in an arbitrary base **b** results in a number at most n+m digits

You can see that easily in base 10: **9*9 = 81** (1 digit * 1 digit = 2 digit) or **99*99 = 9801** (2 digit * 2 digit = 4 digit)

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity, let's take unsigned binary numbers. With n binary digits, you can represent 2^n different numbers, ranging from zero upto 2^n-1. When multiplying an n-digit binary number with an m-digit binary number, the result will be a number between zero and (2^n-1) * (2^m-1) = 2^(n+m) - 2^n - 2^m + 1, which typically is only marginally less than 2^(n+m)-1. To represent such a range of results, you need n+m binary digits.